# How to override Service and Ingress rule in Quarkus kubernetes extension

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, quarkus

I was set kubernetes resource in application.properties

```
# Ingress
quarkus.kubernetes.expose=true
# service will be exposed
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.expose=true
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.host=k8s.cch.dev
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.annotations."nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target"=/$2
# quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.tls.${SECRET_NAME}.enabled=true
# quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.tls.${SECRET_NAME}.hosts=k8s.cch.dev
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.0.host=k8s.cch.dev
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.0.path=/api/v1(/|$)(.*)
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.0.path-type=Prefix
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.0.service-name=${quarkus.container-image.name}
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.0.service-port-name=http
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.0.service-port-number=${quarkus.kubernetes.ports.http.container-port:quarkus.http.port}

quarkus.kubernetes.ports.http.container-port=8080
quarkus.kubernetes.ports.http.path=/
quarkus.kubernetes.ports.http.protocol=tcp
```

But ingress can't override default `path: /`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/commit-id: dbe06014c4986c544ed25fba97f96ac2cecc4091
    app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2022-12-12 - 02:20:45 +0000
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kubernetes-with-quarkus
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kubernetes-with-quarkus
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  name: kubernetes-with-quarkus
  namespace: prod
spec:
  rules:
    - host: k8s.cch.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-with-quarkus
                port:
                  name: http
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
          - backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-with-quarkus
                port:
                  name: http
            path: /api/v1(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
```

How to change `spec.ports.port` to 8080 ? I could't find the configuration on kubernetes extension.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/commit-id: dbe06014c4986c544ed25fba97f96ac2cecc4091
    app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2022-12-12 - 02:20:45 +0000
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/path: /q/metrics
    prometheus.io/port: "8080"
    prometheus.io/scheme: http
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kubernetes-with-quarkus
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kubernetes-with-quarkus
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  name: kubernetes-with-quarkus
  namespace: prod
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kubernetes-with-quarkus
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kubernetes-with-quarkus
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  type: ClusterIP
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is adding to Ingress rules, because you're specifying two paths:

```
# ...
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.0.path=/api/v1(/|$)(.*)
# ...
quarkus.kubernetes.ports.http.path=/
```

Quarkus will try to find a matching ingress rule with path "/api/v1(/|$)(.*)" and if it can't find any, it will add a new one.

Instead, if what you want is to override the default path and service port, you simply need to add these two properties:

```
quarkus.kubernetes.ports.http.host-port=<any other port>
quarkus.kubernetes.ports.http.path=/api/v1(/|$)(.*)
```

Then, if you want to change the generated ingress rule, use:

```
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.0.path=/api/v1(/|$)(.*)
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.rules.0.host or path-type or other ingress rule configuration
```

Because the properties `quarkus.kubernetes.ports...` are not very intuitive in regards to how are related to the generated Ingress resource, there are already plans to improve it: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/29279